# Java data reader skips my empty new lines (\n)

Tags: java, datareader

Okay, I tried everything but I can't find answer. My data reader skips empty next line while reading from a txt file. 
It is supposed to strip all the comments from the txt file and print rest of the data as it is. My reader does strip the comments & prints the data but it skips the empty new lines..

### MyDataReader.java

```
public String readLine()
{
    String buf = new String();
String readStr = new String();

int end = 0;
int done = 0;

try
{
    // checks if line extraction is done and marker has non null value
    while (done != 1 && marker != null)
    {
    readStr = theReader.readLine(); // Reads the line from standard input

    if (readStr != null)
    {
        /* If the first character of line isnt marker */
        if (readStr.length() > 0)
        {
            if (!readStr.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase(marker))
        {
            end = readStr.indexOf(marker);   // checks if marker exists in the string or not
            if (end > 0)
            buf = readStr.substring(0, end);
            else
            buf = readStr;

            done = 1;   // String extraction is done
         }
        }
    }
    else
    {
            buf = null;
        done = 1;
    }
    }
}
// catches the exception
catch (Exception e)
{
    buf = null;
    System.out.println(e);
}

return buf;
}
```

---

### TestMyDataReader.java

```
String myStr = new String();

  myStr = _mdr.readLine();

  while (myStr != null)
  {
      //System.out.println("Original String : " + myStr);
      System.out.println(myStr);
      myStr = _mdr.readLine();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if (readStr.length() > 0)

That's the line of code that is skipping empty lines.

Comment: Thanks.. I will find a way around to deal with comments :D

Comment: DONE... Thanks for pointing out... I didnt know exactly which part was causing the problem. 
Now its working as it should.

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel This line of code skips empty lines. You have another line of code that skips comments. Just delete this line.

Comment: Got rid of it. Added another check.. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

lots of issues in this code, but the main problem that you are dealing with is that new lines are not included in the readLine result.  Thus, your if statement is not true (the line is in fact empty

Comment: LOL... that makes me sad... but I will keep working on it
Can you point out the weaknesses you found in code?
It will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your reader won't include the newline characer in readStr, so reading in the line "\n" will make readStr be "", and

> readStr.length() > 0

Will evaluate to false, thus skipping that line.